# MAMP: How can I run both Vhost sites and default sites

Tags: php, mamp, hosts

So I enabled a vHost in my httpd.conf by enabling `Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and in `/etc/host` I made entry as:

```
127.0.0.1 mydomain.com
```

Now even if I try `localhost` it goes to `mydomain.com`

Answer (score 0):

In the MAMP Environment, Virtual Hosts are quite easy to implement. However, in your case you might have probably forgotten to add some entries to `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`. Adding entries to the `/etc/host` alone is not enough and again (in your case) the line: `127.0.0.1 mydomain.com` says that all requests (no matter which) should be forwarded to mydomain.com

Now to make this work the way you had expected, open up `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and add the following Entries:

```
        # THIS ENSURES THAT localhost IS STILL INTACT...
        <VirtualHost *:80>
            DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
            ServerName localhost
        </VirtualHost>    

        # THIS LOADS UP THE mydomain.com VIRTUAL HOST
        <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
            DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mydomain"
            ServerName mydomain.com
            ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
            ErrorLog "logs/mydomain-error_log"
            CustomLog "logs/mydomain.com-access_log" common
        </VirtualHost>
```

The Lines above ensures that when you call `mydomain.com`, the appropriate Virtual Host is loaded in this case the index File under `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mydomain` but still, calling `localhost` would load the default MAMP Welcome Page (except when configured otherwise).

**IMPORTANT**

Make sure (also) that in your `hosts` File, the entry: `127.0.0.1  localhost` is there (preferably, as the first Entry). In other words, your `hosts` File is expected to look something like this:

```
    ##
    # Host Database
    #
    # localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
    # when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
    ##
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    127.0.0.1       mydomain.com
    255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
    ::1             localhost
```